# widgetlist.xml creation in samsung smart tv app for multiple download

Tags: xml, samsung-smart-tv

I created my smart tv app but I am not able to upload it on tv I checked with tv model and Sdk Compatibility thats all OK

I want sample explanation widgetlist.xml file

which contain multiple download tag and

If we put multiple download tag then what about compression tag is that it will also needs to be write multiple time??

Comment: Post your widgetlist.xml content so that the others can analyze where the wrong part

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`widgetlist.xml`
Sample widgetlist.xml file with multiple apps to sync:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsp stat="ok">
<list>
    <widget id="appName1">
        <title>app name 1</title>
        <compression size="100000" type="zip"/>
        <description></description>
        <download>http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Widget/appName1_20130523.zip</download>
    </widget>
    <widget id="appName2">
        <title>app name 2</title>
        <compression size="500000" type="zip"/>
        <description></description>
        <download>http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Widget/appName2_20130910.zip</download>
    </widget>
</list>
</rsp>
```